# ¿Se puede mostrar datos de MySQL en Android sin utilizar listView?

Tags: android, android-listview

Es posible mostrar datos de una consulta `MySQL` en diferentes `textViews` sin utilizar un `listView`, tomando en consideración que mi consulta `MySQL` me da solo una fila como resultado?

Hasta el momento tengo lo siguiente:

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> employeeList;

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private static final String url_tareas = "http://localhost/test/get_employee.php";
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_EMPLOYEES = "employees";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    public static final String TAG_DESIGNATION = "designation";
    JSONArray employees = null;
    ListView list;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        employeeList = new ArrayList<>();

        new MainActivity.LoadAllProducts().execute();
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

    class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            List params = new ArrayList();
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_tareas, "GET", params);    
            try {
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    employees = json.getJSONArray(TAG_EMPLOYEES);

                    for (int i = 0; i < employees.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = employees.getJSONObject(i);

                        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                        String designation = c.getString(TAG_DESIGNATION);
                        Log.d("","designation1= "+designation);

                        HashMap map = new HashMap();

                        map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                        map.put(TAG_DESIGNATION, designation);

                        employeeList.add(map);
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("","Error= "+e);
            }
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

            pDialog.dismiss();
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this,employeeList,R.layout.single_post,new String[] {
                                    TAG_NAME,
                                    TAG_DESIGNATION,
                            },
                            new int[] {
                                    R.id.txt_name,
                                    R.id.txt_designation_SINGLE_POST,
                            });
                    list.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.user.testbd.MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="37dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

single_post.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="1dp">

    <TextView
        android:text="Name:"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="71dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Designation:"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

    <TextView
        android:text="designation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/txt_name"
        android:id="@+id/txt_designation_SINGLE_POST"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

    <TextView
        android:text="name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="86dp"
        android:id="@+id/txt_name"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Tienes varios TextView en un Layout o deseas se generen programaticamente?

Comment: Tengo varios TextView en un Layout :)

Comment: puedes agregar tu codigo, ya obtienes los datos de la consulta, en un cursor, ArrayList?

Comment: Si ya tengo los datos en un ArrayList en un momento agrego mi código

Comment: Listo @Jorgesys ya agregue mi código

Comment: Creo que lo correcto sería que en onPostExecute obtuvieras el ArrayList  employeeList y por medio de esto llenar el Adapter. En realidad el código que tienes llena un Adapter de un ListView y en cada elemento se vería el layout single_post.xml con datos!.

Comment: Bueno no se si te entendí bien pero lo que pretendo es eliminar el layout activity_main.xml y dejar únicamente el layout sinple_post.xml